# Reflection.Emit create property

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

How can I create Property1 using reflection?

```
public IProp Property1
{
    get
    {
        return new TestClass(TestMethod);
    }
}

private void TestMethod()
{
...
}
```

I'm trying

```
    var propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty("Property1", 
        PropertyAttributes.None, typeof(IProp), Type.EmptyTypes);
    propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(GenerateGetter(typeBuilder, testMethodInfo));

    MethodBuilder GenerateGetter(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, MethodInfo TestMethod)
    {
        var getterBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(TestMethod.Name,
            METHOD_ATTRIBUTES, TestMethod.ReturnType, Type.EmptyTypes);

        var actionCtor = typeof(Action).GetConstructors().Single();
        var testClassCtor = typeof(TestClass).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(Action) });

        var il = getterBuilder.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldftn, TestMethod);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, actionCtor);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, testClassCtor);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return getterBuilder;
    }
```

But I have System.Reflection.TargetException (Object does not match target type). I think I have error because my IL code is bad.

Comment: I'm not sure how sample posted in the question is related to creation of property... Check out  [MSDN Define a Property with Reflection.Emit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1zby21a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, how can I generate get accessor with reflection.emit?

Comment: Please update your question than to clarify what you have problem with. More complete sample may also help someone to answer your question.

Comment: If you are actually trying to generate a property then you are using the incorrect method.  What you have posted above specifically refers to Method construction, not Property construction.

Comment: The error is saying that `testMethodInfo` does not accept the right type. However you don't provide any logic for `testMethodInfo`.

Comment: Just look at what the C# compiler did. This answers 99% of all Reflection Emit questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced

```
var getterBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(TestMethod.Name,
        METHOD_ATTRIBUTES, TestMethod.ReturnType, Type.EmptyTypes);
```

to

```
var getterBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(TestMethod.Name,
        METHOD_ATTRIBUTES, typeof(IProp), Type.EmptyTypes);
```